# Which type of Test is usefull for Jenkins Continous Integration (Spring Boot App)

Tags: java, testing, jenkins, spring-boot

My boss asked me to build some test on our Spring Boot application.

I'm asking myself which type of test should I implement, considering that the goal is to push the app on Jenkins that supports auto Testing.

**Code based Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ConfigTagControllerTestReal {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTheTagName() throws Exception{

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/configtag/librerie"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

**Completely Mock Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ConfigTagController.class , secure = false)
public class ConfigTagControllerTestMocked {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ConfigTagService service;

    @Test
    public void shouldFindTheTagName() throws Exception{

        Collection<String> mockPaths= new ArrayList<>();

        ConfigTagEntity mockTag = new ConfigTagEntity("culo",mockPaths);

        Mockito.when(service.getByName(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockTag);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/configtag/culo")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

    }
```

I'm very new in testing and i need to understand the working method

Comment: Then you should really be reading some good articles/books/tutorials on testing. It's not something that can be taught in an SO answer.